# Software for creating and publishing game cards

Tags: windows, collection-manager, desktop-publishing

I'm looking for a program that can layout and manage custom cards and tokens for tabletop games (eg. Magic the Gathering, Munchkin, Arkham Horror).

I am specifically looking for solutions that support the following:

- Multiple common card sizes
- Customizable card layouts (CSS or similar scripted method as a minimum, drag/drop GUI preferred)
- Collection management and browsing (can handle multiple decks within one project)
- Individual and batch exporting to image (jpg, png or other common image formats) and PDF
- Batch printing

The following features would also be very attractive, but they are not required:

- Support for custom card sizes
- List-style overview of primary card fields
- More advanced set management and browsing (eg. having different expansions within one project and the ability to browse all cards in a deck or only those within a particular expansion of the deck)
- Supports SVG images
- Print/Export with crop guides for manual cutting
- Export to common commercial printer/cutter format(s)

I already know of Magic Set Editor and Strange Eons, and while both fit my needs to a degree I am interested in finding and comparing similar products.

I would prefer open source software, but freeware and commercial software is welcome. Online solutions are acceptable as well.

Comment: Like Bridge cards and Uno cards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html?sdid=JNWPP)

Cost: ~$800 one off, or ~$20 a month (Renting through the Adobe Cloud) 
[Free Trial Here](https://creative.adobe.com/products/indesign)

In the professional world you will find that InDesign, is used.
It is **not** a tool designed specifically for this. 
I believe a large portion of this is because InDesign is already being used for settign the rule book, and in other products by the design team.

- *Multiple common card sizes:* **Partial** You'll have to add the as custom paper size, but they can be saved and used in multiple documents youself as custom paper size
- *Customizable card layouts* **Yes**, Create a master page, and then fill in the rest using XML import, or data merge (also called mail merge), or by creating pages and doing it by hand.
- *Collection management and browsing (can handle multiple decks within one project)*: **Yes** Yes, many *pages* in one *document*, many documents in one *book*, many *books* in one *library*. You can break it down how you want.
- *Individual and batch exporting to image and PDF* **Individual Yes, Batch Partial*, Individually you can convert a *document* to PDF, JPEG, HTML or a couple of other formats. I can only work out how to convert a *book* to PDF or Postscript (via the print book option)
- *Batch printing* **??**, I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but it can print a whole book at at time, and you can set it to collate, do multiple copies etc.
- *Support for custom card sizes* **Yes**, this is the only way you can get card sizes.
- *List-style overview of primary card fields* **Indirect, Partial** if you are managing your fields with data merge or Import XML then you can view them in a list with any CSV/XML viewing tool
- *More advanced set management and browsing* *No*, beyound the ability to organise documents into books etc I mentioned above no.
- *Supports SVG images* **Yes**
- *Print/Export with crop guides for manual cutting*  **Yes**, When exporting go to marks and bleeds and turn on crop marks.
- *Export to common commercial printer/cutter format(s)* **Yes**, Adobe is big enough that it largely defines what commercial printers support.

also, you didn't ask, but it sounded like it would be useful to you:

- *Style sheet equivalent so can change style accorss whole deck:* **Yes**, using character (and/or paragraph styles)

Here is a [blog post](http://www.craycraygames.com/?p=410) where someone talks about how they set it up.
A google will show up that data merge is very popular for making card games.